# Use two different LINQ-To-Entity objects as ItemSource for ListView in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, linq-to-entities, binding

I am using LINQ to Entites where I have two table objects (**ReferenceCodes** and **Stock**) with relationships.

I need to combine both as seperate columns in a ListView like this:

### XAML

```
   <ListView Name="myListView">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Reference Code"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Description"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Using a LINQ statement I am able to set the itemsource of each table separately like this:

### Code Behind

```
Dim Context as New myEntity

myStock = From s In Context.Stocks.ToList
          Select s.Description

myListView.ItemSource = myStock
```

But how do I set each column as a separate item source for each table?  I have tried a join statement like this:

```
Dim Context as New myEntity

myStock = From s In Context.Stocks.ToList
          Join r In Context.ReferenceCodes.ToList
          Select r.ReferenceDescription, s.Description
```

This seems to work except that it only displays a single column in this format:

```
{ ReferenceDescription = ABC1234 ; Description = My stock item description }
```

Instead of two separate columns, one a list of Reference Codes and the other a list of Stock Descriptions.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need to set the [`DisplayMemberBindings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.displaymemberbinding.aspx) of the columns when you have that joined collection of anonymous objects:

```
<ListView Name="myListView">
     <ListView.View>
         <GridView>
             <GridViewColumn Header="Reference Code"
                             DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ReferenceDescription}"/>
             <GridViewColumn Header="Description"
                             DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"/>
         </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

```vb
myListView.ItemsSource = myStock
```

Comment: Thank-you.  That is **EXACTLY** what I was missing.  Works perfectly now!